# Getting Alert when an account's name change - without using a trigger

Tags: email-alert

How can I get an email alert (created) every time an Account's name change?

With out using triggers!

Workflow Rules do NOT let you specify a name change as a parameter

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using workflow rules. when creating a workflow select the "Formula evaluates to true" and  "Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited" options. Use this formula to trigger the email alert whenever the name of the account is changed:

```
ISCHANGED(Name)
```

and then create a email alert as a workflow action.

Answer (score 1):

By Creating a [Workflow Rule](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_rules.htm) attached to Account name change.

Comment: And how to I do that with out using a trigger?